# How to modify the attributes of a file with no extension in C#?

Tags: c#

This is my code

```
static string pat = "C:\\" + System.Environment.UserName + 
              "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History";
FileInfo hist = new FileInfo(pat);
```

Here `History` is a file, with no extension.
All I want to do is this:

```
hist.IsReadOnly = true;
```

But `directorynotfoundexception` comes. Please help me, how do I access the **file**, it thinks that History is a directory!

Comment: What do you get when you run `dir "C:\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History"` (with your user name substituted in for `UserName`)?

Comment: Are you missing the "Users" folder in the beginning of the path? "C:\\USERS" + System.Environment.UserName + "\\AppData\\etc"

Comment: I love you demon! I'm an idiot! So silly! THANKS A LOT!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your path is strange. It starts like "C:\Username\AppData...".

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History");
```

The result will look like this (on XP):

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Username\Local
>   Settings\Application
>   Data\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\History

Windows 7 will give you different result.

This has to work for file with or without extension:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
fi.Attributes |= System.IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

And this has to work for directory:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
di.Attributes |= System.IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work too! It thinks that it's a directory! Same exception :(

Comment: Thanks HABJAN, but I got the error - It should have been "C:\Users\..." instead of "C:\....". I'm a novice, so kindly pardon me. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Ravi Shankar: no problem, but it seems you did not get the point of using System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData). By harcoding "C:\Users\" your application will not work on windows xp. Use GetFolderPath method.

Answer (score 1):

I think your directory is wrong, you seem to be missing the 'Users' folder. It should be:

```
static string pat = "C:\\Users\\" + System.Environment.UserName + ...
```